# Make real time multi line graph with androidplot

Tags: android, androidplot

I would like to know if it's possible to make a real time multiple line graph using androidplot, like [this](https://youtu.be/a20EchSQgpw?t=23m20s) but with 2 lines.And if so if could provide how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its possible.  There's a very similar implementation in the [Androidplot demo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidplot.demos&hl=en_GB) under 'dynamic xy plot example'.

You can find the [full source](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/demoapp/src/main/java/com/androidplot/demos/DynamicXYPlotActivity.java) in the Androidplot Github repo.